# Send a qweb odoo report via to mobile app via api in odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

I have generated odoo qweb report and convert to base64 encoding using the following code.

```
base64.base64encode(pdf)
```

And i get string like

```
"b'JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/KQovQ3JlYXRvciAo/v8AdwBrAGgAdABtAGwAdAB     "
```

now i want to pass this string to mobile application via api.. when i used in mobile..it shows that
"
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
"

base64 encoding odooo

Answer (score 0):

Base64 conversion is fine.
Note that python `base64.base64encode` returns a binary output.

Consider decoding to UTF-8 after encoding into base64.

`base64.base64encode(pdf).decode('utf-8')`

In browser environments (for ex. hybrid mobile or progressive web apps) you should indicate correct mime-type before base64 hash.

`data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKMS...`